# CSS: animated hover with transition for child-element

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

simple problem I guess, but can't seem to find the solution …

Rather simple HTML structure: `.interview` has a child `.overlay` that is `display:none`. When hovering `.interview` I want to fade in the child. However doesn't work.

```
.interview {
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        height:710px;

        /*Transition*/
        transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
        -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
        -o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
}

.interview .overlay {
        position:absolute;
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        display:none;
}


.interview:hover {
     .overlay { display:block };
}
```

Where do I have to put the transition in order to work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **display:none;** removes a block from the page as if it were never there.

use `opacity` instead display property don't work with transition

```css
.interview {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 710px;
  /*Transition*/
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
  -o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
}
.interview .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
.interview:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="interview">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```